# Conditional Incrementing Incorrectly

Tags: c++, c++11

My function

```
int numSteepSegments(const int heights[], int arrSize) {

    int mile = 0, steep_count = 0;

    while (mile <= arrSize) {
        int height = heights[mile];
        int height_next = heights[mile + 1];
        if ((height + 1000) < height_next) {
            ++steep_count;
        } else if ((height - 1000) > height_next) {
            ++steep_count;
        }
        cout << heights[mile] << endl;
        cout << steep_count << endl;

        ++mile;
    }
    return steep_count;
}
```

is spitting out twice as many steep_count than it is supposed to.

With the array:
`1200, 1650, 3450, 2800, 2900, 1650, 1140, 1650, 1200`, and the `arrSize = 9`, what am I missing?

the `cout`'s are:

```
1200
0
1650
1
3450
1
2800
1
2900
2
1650
2
1140
2
1650
2
1200
3
1746942513
4
```

What is that last value? It's obviously not in the array, and I can't see it belonging anywhere near the numbers I'm dealing with. What am I not seeing in my conditionals that's causing the wrong increments to `steep_count`?

Comment: You are going out of bounds for the array not once, but twice. That's Undefined Behaviour. I have no idea what this program is supposed to do, but in order to not exceed array bounds you should change `while (mile <= arrSize)` to `while (mile < arrSize - 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ arrays are zero-based.  The indices for an array with `arrSize` elements range from `0` to `arrSize-1`.

Your loop index `mile` ranges from `0` to `arrSize` (inclusive), so `heights[mile]` is walking off the end of the array.  Also, you are indexing `heights[mile+1]` which would exceed the array limits even if your index were limited to `arrSize-1`.

Try either:

- changing your loop to range from `0` to `arrSize-2` (inclusive), or
- changing your loop to range from `1` to `arrSize-1` and use `mile-1` for the first index.

Comment: So by 'walking off the end of the array', is that huge value at the end just some value stored in adjacent memory or something?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.